# Rust compiler not recognizing a generic trait bound implemented for a struct

Tags: rust, nom

I am using [Nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom), the parser combinator, to write a TOML parser. The parser function I am having trouble with parses a date time string using the [chrono](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono) crate.

```
fn offset_datetime<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(input: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, TomlValue, E> {
    match DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339(input) {
        ParseResult::Ok(dt) => IResult::Ok(("", TomlValue::OffsetDateTime(dt))),
        ParseResult::Err(e) => {
            Err(Err::Error(Error::from_error_kind(input, ErrorKind::Fail)))
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6afd3485512787f8bbf8f38b4e48c919)

In the code above, I am parsing a string slice using `chrono::DatetTime::parse_from_rfc3339`, which returns a `chrono::format::ParseResult`. Then, I am matching it so I can convert it to a proper `nom::IResult`. The `ParseResult::Ok` arm is fine, but I cannot write the correct code for `ParseResult::Err`. Here's the error I get when compiling the code snippet above:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/parser.rs:193:28
    |
188 | fn offset_datetime<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(input: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, TomlValue, E> {
    |                        - this type parameter
...
193 |             Err(Err::Error(Error::from_error_kind(input, ErrorKind::Fail)))
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `E`, found struct `nom::error::Error`
    |
    = note: expected type parameter `E`
                       found struct `nom::error::Error<&str>`
```

The `Error` from `Error::from_error_kind` is one of Nom's own structs, which does [implement](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/b6f79c4d375ae55e1fd1a35032ebb47a52ea3389/src/error.rs#L72) the `ParseError` trait, just as the `E` generic specifies. Why cannot the compiler recognize this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a generic type from a function without generic parameters in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747289/returning-a-generic-type-from-a-function-without-generic-parameters-in-rust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you give a function (`offset_datetime`) a generic parameter (`E`), you are promising that the function can work for *every possible type that `E` could be,* subject to its bounds. Your function signature promises to return an `IResult` with error type `E`. But you do not do that; instead, you return one with error type `nom::error::Error` (using `Error::from_error_kind`).

One possible fix is to change the function signature to return the concrete error type that the function body actually does:

```rust
fn offset_datetime<'a>(input: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, TomlValue, Error<&'a str>> {
```

Another one would be to change the function body to use the generic type the signature claims:

```rust
        ParseResult::Err(e) => Err(Err::Error(E::from_error_kind(input, ErrorKind::Fail))),
```

Note that instead of calling `from_error_kind` on the concrete type `nom::error::Error`, it's calling it on the type variable `E` (which has that method because of the `E: ParseError` bound).

I'm not familiar with how to use `nom` properly, so I can't tell you which of these is more appropriate.